# Mac ssh to Windows PowerShell. Trying to get it to open an app (on the PC). Nothing works, including commands that do it entered directly on the PC

Tags: python, windows, macos, powershell, ssh

Trying to have a python script open an app and then continue on. I have the following setup:

1. Windows PowerShell (PS) running on PC.
2. Mac Terminal running bash. `ssh...` into the PC.

In both windows I get the same "Windows PowerShell, Copyright (C) Microsoft..." etc. info and the same `PS C:\...` prompt.  So it seems I'm in the right place.

Tried various things. In all cases, anything I do directly on the PC that successfully opens the app, when done at the same prompt in the ssh session on the Mac, gives all the same feedback, but doesn't actually open the app.

Things I've tried:

1. `py .\open_mt5.py` at the PS prompt, where that script is:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\MetaTrader 5\\terminal64.exe'])
print(result)
```

2. `py` to start python REPL, then enter the above lines one by one.  Notably, in both setups, the python REPL prompt becomes available immediately (as expected) and the output is the same, but again, the app doesn't open on the PC.
3. Just execute the app from the PS prompt: `C:\'Program Files'\'MetaTrader 5'\terminal64.exe`

...and a few other things.

I think this should work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Or, speaking to the end goal specifically: how can I have my python script, run via ssh, open that app on the PC (and of course not have that block the script from continuing)?

Thanks!

---

Couple of other details if it helps:

- It seems the hiccup is somewhere in the ssh, since that's the difference in all cases. But it also seems to be a Windows thing, because if I ssh into another Mac and enter commands to open Mac apps, they open on the remote Mac, (as expected).
- Everything else I've ever tried via ssh from the Mac (to a Mac or a PC) works the same as it does typing directly into the same prompt on the remote machine, including running an entire python based REST API server on the PC. So I'm pretty sure everything is configured more or less right.
- The app in question needs to be running for my REST API to work as it includes a service that provides some of the functionality. My end goal is have the python script open the app at the start of everything it's doing to set up and run the REST API server, and do so without blocking the rest of the script of course.
- New to python. Self-teaching. Desire to learn it (basics at least). New to Windows command line (cmd, PowerShell). Self-teaching. No desire to learn any more than required for specific project. (Mac/unix user normally). Hoping people can  reply at that level.
- Mac: macOS Monterey 12.4. PC: Windows 10 Home 21H2, python 3.10.5, and the default Win 10 OpenSSH Server.